# Use icon for filetype, but do not open with program

Tags: windows, macos, installation, inno-setup

Let's say there is a filetype (.abc for example), and the goal is to use a custom icon for it, to indicate that it can be opened by our program, but we don't want it to be passed directly to the program (i.e. the program supports this as an import at a later stage, not direct opening).

How would this be accomplished on Windows and OS X?

Using InnoSetup for Windows. OS X installer is undecided at the moment, but either PKG or DMG route should be okay...

For reference, here is the page on InnoSetup indicating how to do this in the case of passing the file to the program: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#assoc

And here is a post describing how to make that sort of direct association on OSX as well: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-open-with-menu

Comment: For windows simply don't create the `shell\open\command` key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;Associate the .abc file type and icon with the Happy Alphabet program.
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".abc"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "abcFile"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "abcFile"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "Happy Alphabet Document"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "abcFile\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{pf}\HappyAlphabet.exe,1"

;Open the Happy Alphabet program when the .abc file is started.
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "abcFile\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{pf}\HappyAlphabet.EXE"" ""%L"""
```

Don't do the last registry operation in the above example if you don't want to start the application when the file is double-clicked.

Comment: Wouldn't a missing `command` key open the *"choose default program"* dialog (I don't know if it's required for this question; I'm just curious and cannot test it now).

Comment: To completely suppress add a command key pointing to the app with a `/donothing` argument and have that either immediately exit or display a message informing the user that the file is for internal use only.

Comment: @AlexK. that sounds like a good compromise even learning the users how to use the app.